# If the performance of an RL agent in a partially observable environment is "good", is this likely only accidental?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process, convergence, pomdp

In my research, I remember to have read that, in case of an environment which can be modeled by partially observable MDP, there are no convergence guarantees (unfortunately, I do not find the paper anymore and I would appreciate if someone can post the link to the reference).

If the performance of an RL agent in a partially observable environment is "good" (i.e. the agent does pretty well in achieving its goal), is this likely only accidental or due to chance?